# php imagepng() gdb debugging information

Tags: php, linux, apache, gdb

```
$img   = imagecreate(110, 20) or die("error!");
$bg    = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 55, 55, 55);
imagestring($img, 5, 0, 3, "leo", $text_color);

imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Apache will crash when you execute this code, I used gdb to debug coredump as follows:

```
$gdb /usr/sbin/httpd /var/apachecoredumps/core.12029
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-100.el7
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /usr/sbin/httpd...Reading symbols from /usr/sbin/httpd...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[New LWP 12029]
[New LWP 12046]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `/usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
0  0x00007f2cd96bafe9 in fill_window () from /lib64/libz.so.1
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install httpd-2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6.x86_64
(gdb) where
0  0x00007f2cd96bafe9 in fill_window () from /lib64/libz.so.1
1  0x00007f2cd96bb5f0 in deflate_slow () from /lib64/libz.so.1
2  0x00007f2cd96bc684 in deflate () from /lib64/libz.so.1
3  0x00007f2cb81c9dfa in png_write_find_filter () from /lib64/libpng15.so.15
4  0x00007f2cb81c4f95 in png_write_row () from /lib64/libpng15.so.15
5  0x00007f2cb81c51db in png_write_image () from /lib64/libpng15.so.15
6  0x00007f2cb8bab2ff in _gdImagePngCtxEx () from /lib64/libgd.so.3
7  0x00007f2cb8dfe149 in _php_image_output_ctx.isra.16 () from /usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so
8  0x00007f2cbc0a45c5 in xdebug_execute_internal () from /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
9  0x00007f2cd172e504 in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
10 0x00007f2cd16c2808 in execute_ex () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
11 0x00007f2cbc0a3a58 in xdebug_execute_ex () from /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
12 0x00007f2cd16870eb in zend_execute_scripts () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
13 0x00007f2cd1621da2 in php_execute_script () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
14 0x00007f2cd173012d in php_handler () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
15 0x0000558429d3da40 in ap_run_handler ()
16 0x0000558429d3df89 in ap_invoke_handler ()
17 0x0000558429d52b0a in ap_process_async_request ()
18 0x0000558429d52de4 in ap_process_request ()
19 0x0000558429d4efe2 in ap_process_http_connection ()
20 0x0000558429d47040 in ap_run_process_connection ()
21 0x00007f2cd499880f in child_main () from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
22 0x00007f2cd4998a55 in make_child () from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
23 0x00007f2cd49996ee in prefork_run () from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
24 0x0000558429d2215e in ap_run_mpm ()
25 0x0000558429d1aed6 in main ()
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your apache httpd.conf, and enable (and maybe install too) the packages it needed, for example:

> Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
>   0 0x00007f2cd96bafe9 in fill_window () from /lib64/libz.so.1

In this case you need libz.

I would recommend to update to php7 too.

After that use this code:

```
<?php
header ("Content-type: image/png");
$img = @ImageCreate (110, 20)
      or die ("error!");
$bg = ImageColorAllocate ($img, 255, 255, 255);
$text_color = ImageColorAllocate ($img, 55, 55, 55);
ImageString ($img, 5, 0, 3, "leo", $text_color);
ImagePNG ($img);
imageDestroy($img);
?>
```

Comment: I see libz in my system,
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root      13 Jul 10 20:22 libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.7

Comment: hi @Matzy ,I can generate a picture by executing this PHP code under the shell but it's not okay to execute it through browser.

Comment: Is the libz in the config enabled? (uncomment the line)

Comment: hi @Matzy ,need to modify the configuration file? is apache or php? i did not find anything about libz in either of these two configuration files

Comment: /etc/apache2/httpd.conf, or apache2.conf (depending on your system)

Comment: hi @Matzy ,My centos7, the configuration file is /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf，but i didn't find anything about libz in the configuration file

Comment: Or reinstall libpng

Comment: If you want, you can check if `imagejpeg` works. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the problem?

You have no debug info installed, this is what gdb is saying in this line:

```
Reading symbols from /usr/sbin/httpd...Reading symbols from /usr/sbin/httpd...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

To get line numbers in bt output, you should install debug info, see another line in gdb output:

```
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install httpd-2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6.x86_64
```

Also note that you will probably need to install debug info for libz and libpng libraries with similar commands.